# How to do automatic login in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a login screen and i am doing login by using some hard cord data.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])




     .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $window,             $ionicModal, $timeout, authService, $state, $http, $ionicLoading, $location) {
         //$window.location.reload();

     $scope.loginSubmitted = false;
    $scope.myflag = false;
     $scope.User = {};
    $scope.toast = function() {
       $ionicLoading.show({
  template: 'wrong credentials'
});
$timeout(function() {
  $ionicLoading.hide();
}, 1000);
        }
         $scope.footerflag = true;
           $scope.hidefooter = function() {
          $timeout(function() {
$scope.footerflag = false;
         },1)
        }
             $scope.showfooter = function() {
   $timeout(function() {
    $scope.footerflag = true;
  },1)
             }


         $scope.doLogin = function() {
console.log("trying login");

//  // var res = $http.post('http://login.com/postLogin', $scope.user);
//  authService.postdetails($scope.User).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
//   $scope.message = data;
//   console.log("succesfn");
//   console.log(status);
//
// })
//  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
//   alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({
//     data: data
//   }));
//   console.log(fail);
// });
$scope.loginSubmitted = true;
$scope.loginstatus = 0;
authService.GetByUsername().success(function(data) {
  $scope.UserData = data;
  // console.log($scope.UserData);
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.UserData.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.UserData[i].UserName == $scope.User.UserName && $scope.UserData[i].Password == $scope.User.Password) {
      authService.currentuser = $scope.User.UserName;
      //console.log(authService.currentuser);
      $scope.loginstatus = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ($scope.loginstatus == 1) {

    // var lastVal = $cookieStore.get($scope.User.UserName);
    // console.log(lastVal);
    //$location.path('/app/playlists');
    $scope.loginstatus = 0;
    $state.go('app.playlists', null, {
      reload: true
    });
  } else {
    console.log('wrong credentials');
    $scope.toast();
  }

}).error(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});


        }



       });
```

So i want to enable automatic login, till the user clicks logout button. How it can be done?
I'm simply redirecting to another page when username and password matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is logged in in the `module.run()` method. Here is an example:
http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/

Answer (score 0):

It might help you.

Please following below links.

1. [How to check authentication and automatically redirect to login state with ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065317/how-to-check-authentication-and-automatically-redirect-to-login-state-with-ui-ro)
2. [angular js returning user autologin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732170/angular-js-returning-user-autologin)